# How to draw all paths from (1,1) to (n,n) by move (+1, 0) or (0, +1)?

Tags: graphics

Now I can draw some grid:

[image]

But what I want(I'm sorry for the weird line. I have no image processing software in my mac...):

[image]

Please notice:

```
f(1, 1) = f(2, 1) = f(3, 1) = 1
f(1, 1) = f(1, 2) = f(1, 3) = 1 
f(2, 2) = f(1, 2) + f(2, 1) = 2 
f(3, 3) = f(3, 2) + f(2, 3) = 2*(f(2, 2) + f(1, 2)) = 2*3 = 6
```

So there is 6 paths from (1,1) to (n,n) by two possible moves: (+1,0), (0, +1).

My question is, how to draw all paths into the grid with different color or different label?

I know the number of paths may be very large when n grows and I just want to make a nice illustration about that problem. So you can assume n <= 5.

Comment: So you want to enumerate all possible Manhattan paths between two lattice points, then…

Comment: @J.M. You are right. I just want to make a nice illustration about that problem, so I won't draw a very large one...(You may assume n <= 5..)

Comment: It might actually be more convenient to start at $(0,0)$ instead, but of course a translation will take care of it if you really want $(1,1)$ as the origin.

Comment: @J.M. Both start at (0, 0) and (1, 1) is OK, since the output(the illustration) remains the same.

Comment: The numbre of  paths is the problem that started me into programming in my freshman college year.  Proper Mathematica function for computing is Multinomial, which lends itself to more dimensions easily.  For example, the number of paths along the edges of a *n*-dimensional hypercube is ({#1, Multinomial @@ ConstantArray[1, #1]} & ) /@ Range[0, 6] and yields {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 24}, {5, 120}, {6, 720}}.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Stealing half of evanb's answer we could do:

```
With[{n = 3}, Graphics[{
   LightGray, Disk[#, 0.5] & /@ Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}], 1],
   Thick, Module[{m, paths = Sort@Permutations[Join @@ ({{0, 1}, {1, 0}} & /@ Range[n])]},
    m = Length@paths; 
    Table[{Hue[(i - 1)/(m - 1)], Line@FoldList[Plus, 
        1/(2 Sqrt[2]) {-1 + (2 (-1 + i))/(-1 + m), 
          1 - (2 (-1 + i))/(-1 + m)}, paths[[i]]]}, {i, m}]
    ]}]]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: That looks good..

Comment: With a few simplifications: `With[{n = 3}, Graphics[{LightGray, Array[Disk[{##}, 1/2] &, {n + 1, n + 1}, {0, 0}], Thick, With[{m = Binomial[2 n, n]}, MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @@ #2, Line[FoldList[Plus, Rescale[Join[#2, m - #2 + 1], {1, m}, {-1, 1}]/(2 Sqrt[2]), #1]]} &, Sort[Permutations[Join @@ Table[IdentityMatrix[2], {n}]]]]]}]]`

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, it was a bit of an ugly rush job (which seems to have blown up overnight).  If anyone is feeling really sassy, they could sort out the crossovers on the top right.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the `Graph` capabilities to solve this problem.  First, note that every path from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$ has $2n-2$ moves, so it is just a matter of using `FindPath` with `GridGraph`

```
n = 3;
g = GridGraph[{n, n}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
FindPath[g, 1, n n, {2 n - 2}, All] /. 
 Thread[Range[n n] -> GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

[image]

You can visualize all the paths with `PathGraph`,

```
With[{n = 4},
 g = GridGraph[{n, n}];
 HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@#] & /@ 
  FindPath[g, 1, n n, {2 n - 2}, All]]
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate@%
```

[image]

### Edit

Here is a method, less simple than above, but still distinctly different from kirma's answer, that answer's OP's request to draw all of the paths together in a manner in which they are all visible.

```
gridpaths[n_] := Module[{g, coords, paths},
  g = GridGraph[{n, n}, EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0]];

  coords[offs_] := Thread[Range@(n n) -> (offs + GraphEmbedding@g)];
  paths = FindPath[g, 1, n n, 2 n - 2, All];
  Show[
   PathGraph[#1,
      VertexCoordinates -> #1 /. coords[#3],
      EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, #2],
      VertexSize -> 0] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{paths,
      ColorData[97] /@ Ordering@paths,
      Subdivide[-.3, .3, Length@paths - 1]}]}],
   GridLines -> {#, #} &@Range[0.5, n + .5, 1],
   PlotRange -> {{.5, n + .5}, {.5, n + .5}}
   ]
  ]
```

It can be tested via

```
gridpaths /@ Range[2, 7]
```

[image]

Comment: With directed `GridGraph` you don't need to care about path length.

Comment: @kirma - Thanks, I'm new to Graphs.  BTW, I wrote this before fully reading the question or all the answers, so I'm now aware that you already covered the `FindPath` solution, just leaving this since it's so short.  And I'm now aware that yours is so much longer since you went through the trouble of reading and answering the actual question (showing all the paths in a nice fashion).

Comment: Your solution is shorter, though! :)

Comment: @JasonB  neat! +1 :)

Answer (score 18):

You could try something like this:

```
Show[Graphics[{RandomColor[], Line[#]}] & /@ ( (* Make graphics of *)
FoldList[Plus, RandomReal[{0, 0.1}, 2] + {0, 0}, #] & /@ (* Trajectories built from *)
Permutations[ (* All possible orderings of *)
    Join @@ ({{0, 1}, {1, 0}} & /@ Range[5]) (* Five steps N and five steps E*)
   ]
)]
```

The `RandomReal[{0,0.1},2]` is a random near-the-origin starting location, just to offset the different lines from one another visually.

[image]

Comment: I would post a screen shot, but imgur is blocked at work.

Comment: It's correct but I think it's not good enough to illustrate...

Comment: Well, if you don't do the outer-most `Show`, it will produce 252 images, from which you can pick and choose.

Comment: In fact, your way of producing permutations inspires me a lot.. Really thanks!

Comment: @evanb Added the output for you, hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: Nope, don't mind at all! :)

Answer (score 14):

A solution just to show `Solve` can also be used directly on basis of the problem specification:

```
With[{max = 4},
  With[{coords = Table[{x[n], y[n]}, {n, 2 max - 1}]},
    coords /. Solve[
       (* the first and last points *)
       {x[1] == y[1] == 1,
        x[2 max - 1] == y[2 max - 1] == max, 
        (* intermediate constrained steps *)
        Sequence @@ Table[
          x[n + 1] == x[n] + 1 && y[n + 1] == y[n] || 
           x[n + 1] == x[n] && y[n + 1] == y[n] + 1,
          {n, 2 max - 2}]}, 
      Flatten@coords]] // 
  (* the rest is just formatting output *)
  Function[sols, 
     MapIndexed[#1 + 
        Table[{1/2, -1/2} + {-1, 1} First@#2/Length@sols, Length@#] &, 
      sols]] // ListLinePlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &]
```

> [image]

Another solution finding all paths on a directed `GridGraph`, giving the same result:

```
With[{max = 4}, 
 With[{g = 
      VertexReplace[GridGraph[{max, max}, DirectedEdges -> True],
       (* convert vertex numbers to coordinates, 
          working around what seems like a pattern matching bug... *)
       Flatten@Table[
         FromDigits[{x, y} - {1, 1}, max] + 1 -> {x, y},
          {x, max}, {y, max}]]},
    (* find all paths in a directed grid graph *)
    FindPath[g, {1, 1}, {max, max}, \[Infinity], All]] //
   (* the rest is just formatting output *)
   Function[sols, 
    MapIndexed[#1 + 
       Table[{1/2, -1/2} + {-1, 1} First@#2/Length@sols, Length@#] &, 
     sols]] // ListLinePlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &]
```

Comment: Ah, I was going to post a `GridGraph[]` solution when I got home... oh well. +1!

Answer (score 12):

```
g[n_] := Module[{tup = Tuples[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, 2 n]},
   Pick[tup, Total[#] == {n, n} & /@ tup]];
fun[n_] := 
 With[{r = Accumulate /@ (Join[{{1/2, 1/2}}, #] & /@ g[n])}, 
  Join @@ MapIndexed[ 
    Panel[#1, ToString[#2[[1]]] <> " of " <> ToString[Length@r]] &,
    Table[ListPlot[#[[1 ;; j]], Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
        PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick},
        PlotRange -> Table[{0, n + 1}, {2}], 
        GridLines -> {Range[0, n], Range[0, n]}, Frame -> True, 
        FrameTicks -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic], {j, 1, 
        2 n + 1}] & /@ r, {2}]]
```

The animation is not efficient.  Others will doubt have better ways.
I only illustrate paths from {1,1} (lower left hand corner) to {4,4}.

```
dat = fun[3];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

So, paths can be found by traversing a grid graph. But also, they can be stacked in a 3D graphic.

```
paths[rows_, cols_] := FindPath[
  GridGraph[{rows, cols}], 1, rows*cols,
  ManhattanDistance[{1, 1}, {rows, cols}] + 1, All]
```

This has the advantage of rotating the stack and looking at it from different view points.

```
draw3D[rows_, cols_, options___] :=
 Module[{lines, hues},
  lines = Module[{z = 0},
    paths[rows, cols] /. path : {__Integer} :> (z += 1; Line[
        {Quotient[#, rows, 1], Mod[#, rows, 1], z} & /@ path])];
  hues = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range@Length@lines];
  Graphics3D[{Thick, JoinForm["Round"], Transpose[{hues, lines}]},
   options,
   ImageSize -> Small,
   BoxRatios -> {cols, rows, Min[cols, rows]},
   Boxed -> False]]

draw3D[4, 3, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved using Permutations[], Accumulate[] and the graphics commands.

Letting, for simplicity,

```
rep = {{1, 0} -> x, {0, 1} -> y};
```

The list of all paths is given simply by all different step sequences

```
stepsequs[n_] := Permutations[Join[Array[x &, n], Array[y &, n]]]
```

Example

```
stepsequs[3]

(* Output suppressed *)
```

The number of paths is obviously given by

```
nPaths[n_] := Binomial[2 n, n]
```

checking some values: ok

```
Table[{nPaths[n], Binomial[2 n, n]}, {n, 1, 5}]

(* Out[179]= {{2, 2}, {6, 6}, {20, 20}, {70, 70}, {252, 252}} *)
```

The graphical representation can be done in a primitive form like this

First, we add the start Point, and we do this with a random shift (in order to be able to distinguish different paths, which works only to a certain degree, I admit)

```
r := RandomReal[]/10

sequ[n_] := Join[{{r, r}}, #] & /@ stepsequs[n] /. {x -> {1, 0}, y -> {0, 1}}
```

The lines to be drawn are generated from the step sequence using Accumulate[]

Putting things together we arrive at

```
With[{n = 3}, Show[Graphics[Line[Accumulate /@ sequ[n]]]]]
```

[image]

Remark: my graphis abilities are very limited. Others have provided nice pictures already.