# Counting all perpendicular paths crossing a grid

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm new to Mathematica and thus don't really have any idea how to code what I need. My current research involves counting all possible paths that start at (0,0) and terminate at (n-1,n-1) on an n x n grid. The restriction is that any such paths cannot travel in the same direction twice in a row - e.g. a path that goes UP, RIGHT, RIGHT, UP on a 3x3 grid is invalid. I talked with a professor of mine about this but I'm still lost, even on the brute forcing methods, so I figured I would ask for help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a problem in mathematics (combinatorics), and not the *Mathematica* programming language.

Comment: Yes, but I wish to enumerate small cases of this problem.

Comment: @SAWblade You might be interested in `GridGraph` and `FindPath` then. I suspect that you will still have to figure out logic to exclude the unacceptable paths.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you can only have UP and RIGHT as moves, or if LEFT and DOWN also work.  You might find inspiration from the answers [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112395/9490)

Comment: assuming "RIGHT" and "UP" are the only allowed directions:  maybe `paths = {#, RotateRight@#} &@Flatten@Table[{"RIGHT", "UP"}, {n - 1}]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[n_, dir : "UP" | "RIGHT" : "RIGHT"] := Module[{init=If[dir == "RIGHT", {1, 0}, {0, 1}]}, 
  FoldList[Plus, {0, 0}, NestList[Reverse, init, 2 n - 3]]]
```

Examples:

```
f[5]
```

> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}}

```
f[5, "UP"]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}}

Graphics:

```
n = 4; 
Graphics[{Point[Tuples[Range[0, n], 2]], Red,  Line[f[n]], Blue, Line[f[n, "UP"]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2-1, 20], #]&, Outer[List, Range[0, n],Range[0, n]], {2}],
  Red,  Line[f[n]], Blue, Line[f[n, "UP"]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]