# Linear Integer Programming-Find all path on a GridGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to solve my birth and death problem.

```
SeedRandom[124]
With[{λ = 3, μ = 2, initialPopulation = 10, 
numOfReaction = 5, numOfSim = 1}, 
ListLinePlot[
  sim = birthDeath[λ, μ, initialPopulation, 
    numOfReaction], InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> Transpose@sim, FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Population"}, 
  ImageSize -> 300]]
```

[image]

And one possible[image] path is

> sim={{0, 10}, {0.168871, 9}, {0.824082, 10}, {0.92576, 11}, {0.956336, 
>     12}, {1.06251, 11}}

```
Differences@sim[[All, 1]]
```

> deltaT={0.168871, 0.655211, 0.101678, 0.0305756, 0.106177}

after 0.168871s there is a death but it could be a birth and after 0.655211s there is birth but it could be death and so on.

Initial population is 10 and end up with population 11 after some number of birth and death.Number of reaction is constant  which is 5 in this case namely 2 death, 3 birth.
I would like to find All path between initial population and last population. I thought I can use Graph and find all path that satisfy the condition.

Do you think it is better to use Linear Integer Programming? Total population cannot be negative. Sum of #birth and #death=last population-initial population. birth and death are integer.

Assume I have $5\times5$ `GridGraph`. I would like to find all path (not necessarily shortest ) under some condition.

1. Start from initial population and always move to Right, Up Or Down at the beginning.
2. You cannot move Right and Right consecutively. Meaning that after Right  either  move UP or Down if possible.
3. Never move Left.

Here is the sample code I got from Help page which violets some rules I have.

```
 s = 1;
    t = 16;
    g = GridGraph[{4, 4}, VertexSize -> {s -> Medium, t -> Medium}]

path=FindPath[g, s, t, {GraphDistance[g, s, t]}, All]

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[#]] & /@ path
```

[image]

Comment: If "you always move to the right at the beginning" and "you cannot move right and right," then your problem is a general shortest search on a $3 \times 3$ grid.  All valid paths "start" at the location $(1,1)$ and exclude the three "right-right" paths that remain.

Comment: Yes you right. Let me fix my condition.

Comment: I just realized that graph approach may not be a good idea.

Comment: loosely/ tangentially related: [Counting all perpendicular paths crossing a grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137418/125)

Comment: What about Up + Up? Or Up+Down?

Comment: Up + Up Or Up+Down not possible. Basically time between reactions is Exp distributed. So deltaT~Exp [lambda] and each deltaT population increases by 1 or decreases by 1.

Comment: Can you go Up or Down after reaching the right side?

Comment: Start with position {0, 10} and end with  position {1.06251, 11} . The answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one idea. First, let's look at the vertex labels:

```
g = GridGraph[{5, 5}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Since [`FindPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath) doesn't revisit vertices, we don't have to worry about `up` + `down` paths. The paths that [`FindPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath) generates that are not allowed are the `up` + `up`, `down` + `down` and `right` + `right` (in addition to `left`). I use the following to encode this information:

```
up = {
    {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 9}, {8, 9, 10},
    {11, 12, 13}, {12, 13, 14}, {13, 14, 15},
    {16, 17, 18}, {17, 18, 19}, {18, 19, 20},
    {21, 22, 23}, {22, 23, 24}, {23, 24, 25}
};

down = Reverse /@ up;

right = {
    {1, 6, 11}, {6, 11, 16}, {11, 16, 21},
    {2, 7, 12}, {7, 12, 17}, {12, 17, 22},
    {3, 8, 13}, {8, 13, 18}, {13, 18, 23},
    {4, 9, 14}, {9, 14, 19}, {14, 19, 24},
    {5, 10, 15}, {10, 15, 20}, {15, 20, 25}
};

left = {
    {6, 1}, {11, 6}, {16, 11}, {21, 16},
    {7, 2}, {12, 7}, {17, 12}, {22, 17},
    {8, 3}, {13, 8}, {18, 13}, {23, 18},
    {9, 4}, {14, 9}, {19, 14}, {24, 19},
    {10, 5}, {15, 10}, {20, 15}, {25, 20}
};
```

Using the above data, we can create a function to determine whether a path is allowed or not:

```
goodQ[path_, set_, len_] := Max[
    Length[LongestCommonSubsequence[path, #]]& /@ set
] < len

goodQ[path_] := And[
    goodQ[path, left, 2],
    goodQ[path, right, 3],
    goodQ[path, up, 3],
    goodQ[path, down, 3]
]
```

Finally, we can construct all the paths and then select only the good ones:

```
paths = Join @@ Table[
    FindPath[g, 1, end, 9, All],
    {end, 21, 25}
];
good = Select[paths, goodQ]
```

> {{1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 17, 22, 21}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22, 21}, {1, 2, 
>     7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 16, 21}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 16, 21}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 
>     13, 18, 17, 22}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 18,
>      23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 16,
>      21, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 16,
>      21, 22}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 23}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 17, 22, 
>     23}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22, 23}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 18, 
>     23}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23}, {1,
>      6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 20, 25, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 
>     8, 13, 14, 19, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 
>     6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 25}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 
>     13, 14, 19, 20, 25}}

Visualization:

```
Multicolumn[
    HighlightGraph[
        Graph[g, EdgeStyle->LightGray, VertexLabels->None],
        BlockMap[Apply[UndirectedEdge], #, 2, 1]
    ]& /@ good,
    3
]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

If we only want paths that start at 1 and end at 22, with 3 `up` steps and 2 `down` steps, then the path has length 9:

```
paths = FindPath[g, 1, 22, {9}, All];
good = Select[paths, goodQ]
```

> {{1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 18, 23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23, 
>     22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 16, 21, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 
>     22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 16, 21, 22}}

Visualization:

```
Multicolumn[
    HighlightGraph[
        Graph[g, EdgeStyle->LightGray, VertexLabels->None],
        BlockMap[Apply[UndirectedEdge], #, 2, 1]
    ]& /@ good,
    3
]
```

[image]

**Update**

Here's a version of `goodQ` that should generalize better:

```
goodQ[path_] := With[{d = Differences[path]},
    With[{odd = Tally[Abs[d][[1;;-1;;2]]], even = Tally[Abs[d][[2;;-1;;2]]]},
        Min[d]>=-1 && Length[odd]==1 && Length[even]==1 &&odd!=even
    ]
]
```

Check:

```
paths = Join@@Table[FindPath[g, 1, end, 9, All], {end, 21, 25}];
good = Select[paths, goodQ]
```

> {{1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 17, 22, 21}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22, 21}, {1, 2, 
>     7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 16, 21}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 16, 21}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 
>     13, 18, 17, 22}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 18,
>      23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 16,
>      21, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 22}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 16,
>      21, 22}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 23}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 17, 22, 
>     23}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 11, 16, 17, 22, 23}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 18, 
>     23}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23}, {1, 2, 7, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23}, {1,
>      6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 20, 25, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 
>     8, 13, 14, 19, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 2, 7, 
>     6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24}, {1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 18, 19, 24, 25}, {1, 2, 7, 8, 
>     13, 14, 19, 20, 25}}

Same answer as before.

Comment: Number of birth and death shouldn't change. Since I have 2 down (death) and 3 up (birth), path should 2 down (death) and 3 up (birth), order may change. It should start at the  position {0, 10} and end at the  position {1.06251, 11}

Comment: your method is promising but what if I wanna try 6x6 or other grid size, then defining vectors(left, right, up) will be cumbersome. Can your approach be generalized?