# Split $n$-dimensional prism into simplices

Tags: geometry, simplex

Are there standard geometry or graph functions that allow to, say, construct a $n$-dimensional prism by it's $(n-1)D$ base and height and split it into simplices (without creating new points)?

Extra question:
Is it possible to do the same for cartesian product of two triangles (here is a graph of such structure):

```
a = CompleteGraph[3];
b = CompleteGraph[3];
at = Table[Subscript[VertexList[a][[i]],A], {i, 1, Length[VertexList[a]]}];
bt = Table[Subscript[VertexList[b][[i]],B], {i, 1, Length[VertexList[b]]}];
fl = Flatten[
Table[at[[i]] bt[[j]], {i, 1, Length[VertexList[a]]}, {j, 1, 
Length[VertexList[b]]}]];
edges = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[fl], i++,
For[j = 1, j <= Length[fl], j++,
If[(fl[[i, 1]] == fl[[j, 1]] || fl[[i, 1]] == fl[[j, 2]] || 
    fl[[i, 2]] == fl[[j, 1]] || fl[[i, 2]] == fl[[j, 2]]) && 
i != j, AppendTo[edges, fl[[i]] <-> fl[[j]]]]
];
];
F1 = Graph[DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ edges]];
Graph[F1, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: What is the range of `n`? If it is 1, 2 or 3 then `ConvexHullMesh` might do what you want. In the more general case: If the base is already divided into simplices then the task can be reduced to splitting a simplicial prism...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `n` is 6. I was wondering if there is something like geometry computations that would allow to add and subtract one general geometry from another. Base is a simplex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First suppose you have $n$ points in $(n-1)$-dimensional vector space in general position (their span is the whole $(n-1)$-dimensional space) as your base. You can get $n$ simplices (I'm using lists of vectors instead of actual simplices) of dimension $n$ from the prism based at these $n$ points and extruded up into the $n$th dimension in the following way:

```
SimplexPrismSplit[PList_] := Module[{dim = Length[PList]},
  PBase = Table[Join[PList[[k]], {0}], {k, 1, dim}];
  PTop = Table[Join[PList[[k]], {1}], {k, 1, dim}];
  Table[Union[Take[PBase, {1, k}], Take[PTop, {k, dim}]], {k, 1, dim}]]
```

I've assumed the base is situated in $n$-space with $0$ as its $n$th coordinate, and the top of the prism with $1$ as its $n$th coordinate.

If you have $k>n$ points as your base, choose an "appropriate" collection of subsets of size $n$ and then proceed as above. By "appropriate" I mean split up the base into $k-n+1$ disjoint smaller bases each defined by $n$ points. I'm not sure how to tell Mathematica how to do this "appropriate" step, but that's the intuition. For example, if $n=3$, you want to split up your polygonal base into smaller bases, each of which is a triangle, as below.

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:** Given the example, there is a bit more going on that I can try to explain, but I'm not sure how to code it. For a prism, a base $B=\{a,b,c\}$ times the interval $I=\{0,1\}$, this is how the simplices were chosen (my intuition was only coming from the proof of the functoriality of singular homology, as in [Proposition 25 here](http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math534_1011/homology.pdf), but only because of the word "prism"):

[image]

For a simplex $S_1$ times another simplex $S_2$, the natural (to me) generalization seems to be to take all north-east [lattice paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path) on the grid of vertices $S_1\times S_2$. For example, if $S_1$ and $S_2$ are both 3-dimensional:

[image]

Dimension counting works out (if $\dim(S_1)=k$ and $\dim(S_2)=\ell$, then the dimension of the product is $k+\ell$, as is the dimension of a simplex defined by every north-east lattice path). It also makes some topological sense, as all simplices made in such a way share a face of dimension $k+\ell-1$ (as we are changing one vertex at a time).

Hopefully that gives you some intuition on how to make an algorithm that finds all such paths. I would actually guess Mathematica has such a built-in function, I am just too uninformed to know how to look for it.

---

**EDIT 2:** For posterity, here is the code that gives dimension $k+\ell$ simplices in the product of a $k$-simplex with an $\ell$-simplex, borrowing from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112395/how-to-draw-all-paths-from-1-1-to-n-n-by-move-1-0-or-0-1/112411#112411).

```
SplitProduct[L1_, L2_] := 
  Module[{dim1 = Length[L1], dim2 = Length[L2]}, 
   L1xL2 = Flatten[
     Table[Join[L1[[i]], L2[[j]]], {j, 1, dim2}, {i, 1, dim1}], 1];
   g = GridGraph[{dim1, dim2}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
   Paths = FindPath[g, 1, dim1*dim2, dim1 + dim2 - 2, All];
   Table[Table[L1xL2[[i]], {i, P}], {P, Paths}]];
```

Here `L1` is a list of $k+1$ $k$-tuples and `L2` is a list of $\ell+1$ $\ell$-tuples. I don't have a convincing argument of why every point in the product is contained in a simplex that the code produces. However, the following code shows that all the simplices are disjoint (thanks to @VsevolodA).

```
{k, l} = {3, 3};
S1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {k + 1, k}];
S2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {l + 1, l}];
Simplices = SplitProduct[S1, S2];
RandVec = Table[0.0000001 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, k + l], {i, 1, k + l}];
Table[Fold[Or, 
  Table[RegionDisjoint[Simplex[pair[[1]]], 
    Simplex[Table[w + v, {w, pair[[2]]}]]], {v, RandVec}]], {pair, 
  Subsets[Simplices, {2}]}]
```

The code slightly budges a simplex in random directions, and if at least one of them gives a completely disjoint pair, then they only share a lower-dimensional face, as desired. So if the code returns a list of `True`, it means all pairs are disjoint.

Comment: That was really cool, thanks. Do you think something as simple can be applied to splitting cartesian product of two simplices?

Comment: @VsevolodA. can you give me an example of a "cartesian product of two simplices" in your context (maybe as a Mathematica object)? If your [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_(geometry)) is $B\times I$, where $B$ is your base and $I=[0,1]$, then using the vertices of $B$ as the input to the function I described should work.

Comment: That's right, however it's $B\times B$, where $B$ is a triange (or tetrahedron). I added graph of such object to the question.

Comment: @VsevolodA. I edited my question to reflect your example, although without Mathematica code, because it is beyond my skill level.